# Tomcat 8 - POST and PUT requests slow when deployed on RHEL

Tags: java, spring, performance, tomcat8, rhel

I have developed a REST API using Spring Framework. When I deploy this in Tomcat 8 on RHEL, the response times for POST and PUT requests are very high when compared to deployment on my local machine (Windows 8.1). On RHEL server it takes 7-9 seconds whereas on local machine it is less than 200 milliseconds.

RAM and CPU of RHEL server are 4 times that of local machine. Default tomcat configurations are used in both Windows and RHEL. Network latency is ruled out because GET requests take more or less same time as local machine whereas time taken to first byte is more for POST and PUT requests.

I even tried profiling the remote JVM using Visual JVM. There are no major hotspots in my custom code.

[image]

I was able to reproduce this same issue in other RHEL servers. Is there any tomcat setting which could help in fixing this performance issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The profiling log you have placed means nothing, more or less. It shows the following:

The blocking queue is blocking. Which is normal, because this is its purpose - to block. This mean there is nothing to take from it.

It is waiting for connection on the socket. Which is also normal.

You do not specify what is your RHEL 8 physical/hardware setup. The operating system here might not be the only thing. You can not eliminate still network latency. What about if you have SAN, the SAN may have latency itself. If you are using SSD drive and the RHEL is using SAN with replication you may experience network latecy there.

I am more inclined to first check the IO on the disk than to focus on operating system. If the server is shared there might be other processes occupying the disk.

You are saying that the latency is ruled out because the GET requests are taking the same time. This is not enough to overrule it as I said this is the latency between the client and the application server, it does not check the latency between your app server machin and your SAN or disk or whatever storage is there.